# Is it possible to remotely check a JMeter slave machine?

Tags: jmeter

We are setting up a load testing platform and developping some tools in go.

We'd like to remotely check a JMeter load generator and (if possible) get some statistics or infos from a JMeter daemon. This will be from a utility developed in go (the language isn't the concern here) so outside from JMeter GUI. The idea is to display the status of the slaves machine (daemon up or down, latest errors, etc.).

At first, I thought to try to open a network connection to the JMeter process, but I don't know if it would interfere with a load test in progress or if there is an API that would expose more information (errors, load genrator currently in use, etc.).

Thank you for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at this although it does not exactly fit your needs:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server

If you're willing to contribute, then you might want to open a discussion on [JMeter Dev Mailing](http://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html) list with your ideas and get dev team advices.

Edit (18 June 2015) :

See:

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201506.mbox/%3CCAH9fUpajsEz8KEMkEVrU4UBYXxdJC2JvJ%3Dw%3DTpmn2ucgoFDX7w%40mail.gmail.com%3E
  This feature would be interesting in JMeter core.